# what's wrong with my javascript promise code

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to implement a javascript promise by myself to understand the mechanism, here is my code, but it report undefined error, could someone help me to take a look?

```
var Promise = function(){
    this.successesCallback = [];
}

Promise.prototype.then = function(success){
    console.log("add success");
    this.successesCallback.push(success);
}

var Defer = function(){
    this.promise = new Promise();
}

Defer.prototype.resolve = function(){
    console.log("defer resolve is calling");
    console.log("2promise of defer:" + this.promise)
    this.promise.successesCallback[0]();
}

var remoteCall = function(callBack){
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
    }
    callBack();
}

var callRemote = function(){
    var defer = new Defer();
    console.log("promise of defer:" + defer.promise)
    console.log("set timer for remote call");
    setTimeout(function(){remoteCall(defer.resolve)}, 0);
    console.log("remote call is triggered");

    return defer.promise;
}

callRemote().then(function(){console.log("Hello, server call done")});
```

You can run by node

Comment: Add more details related to you problem and things you have already tried to resolve issue.

Comment: Wow, a _ton_ of things are wrong in your promise code. For one, your promises don't implement a `then` correctly since you cannot return a promise from the `then`, there is no error handling (a catch), and errors in the promise chain cannot be recovered from.

Comment: Have a look at some minimal "promise" libraries linked to [here](https://promisesaplus.com/implementations) to see how far short your "implementation" of a well known spec really is

Answer (score 2):

you lose the binding between `defer` and `resolve()` in the `setTimeout()` callback.

One solution would be to use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
setTimeout(function(){remoteCall(defer.resolve.bind( defer )}, 0);
```

Comment: This is it. Thanks so much.

Comment: @JasonDou If an answer solved your problem, please "accept" it with the checkmark next to it, so others can see, that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You lose the binding between `defer` and `resolve()` in the `setTimeout()` callback, as mentioned in the other answer. Now you can use `()=>` instead of `function()` to maintain the current binding since ES6.

```
setTimeout(()=>{remoteCall(defer.resolve)}, 0);
```